# How to create a hover effect that changes background color and looks rounded

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a hover effect on a text (p) HTML element. I want the background color of the text element to change, and also, to look oval-shaped. See picture below of what I am trying to achieve. I can't figure out how to get the oval shape - when I add border radius, it rounds the corners, but not the left and right sides.

Desired effect:

[image]

Here is the closest I've gotten:

```css
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 10px;
```

I know I need to add padding on the left...but just trying to figure out the oval shape first.

[image]

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you try increasing the border-radius?

Comment: Yeah, that just results in the corners being more and more rounded...but the left/right sides remain a square shape.

Comment: You know what though, I was just doing it wrong. 100px works...whereas 100% does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have found to always work is to set a border radius that is higher than the total height of the button, eg: 100px or even 200px to be safe.

https://codepen.io/Luke-Johns-lukeybytes/pen/WNmGXpW

```
.rounded {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well did you tried

```
p:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50% / 10px;
}
```

hope this will help you